# Sequence of rectangles/circles with blue lines (straight/zigzag) and small red triangles/circles inside

Tags: visual, sequence

[image: puzzle]

I saw this question in an IQ test, but I have no idea after thinking for very long time.

Comment: Can you give the source of where this is from?

Comment: A friend sent me yesterday and he told me that it is from an IQ test online

Comment: @SunnyTsoi Please send the link.